# Problems with deploy

Tags: docker, deployment, gitlab

I've got problem when deploying to server getting the below error (screen 1). After machine restart I can't install gitlab-runner. Any idea where the problem is?

[image: Screen 1]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in your second screen, you have `no space left` on your disk (in `/tmp`)

You have to increase the disk space in order to allow accomplish your commands.

Comment: Thank you, it dod help, however now I can't send image to repository e.g. docker push command https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T707H7YekenLKZb6jsia_zMcvM_1yN4V/view?usp=sharing. Any idea what causes the problem?

Comment: Is your first problem resolved ? If yes please consider marking an answer as solution. If you have a new problem, please post a new question :)

Comment: Yes, it is. I've posted new question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1084039/sending-image-to-repository-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1415227_1084039