# Sending image to repository not working

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I've got problem with sending image to repository e.g. docker push command. Any idea what causes it?

[image]

Comment: `access denied` sounds like wrong credentials to me.

Comment: Credentials haven't been changed and previous sends went ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access denied, refers to a lack of permission to use the resource. You need to review if your repos have the level of permissions to push changes to a repository.

To grant a repository the permission to push [follow these steps](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/granting-users-access#grant_push_permissions_for_a_repository):

1. In the Google Cloud Console, open Cloud Source Repositories in the
   My source view tab.
2. Click the name of a repository.
3. The Files view opens.
4. Click Settings settings.
5. The General settings page opens.
6. Click Permissions.
7. The Permissions page opens.
8. In the Members field, enter the user's email address.
9. In the Role drop-down list, select Source repository > Source
   Repository Writer.
10. Click Add.

Cloud Source Repositories uses [IAM for access control](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control). You can use IAM to add team members to your project and to grant them permissions to create, view, and update repositories.

Use the table [in this page](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control#roles_and_permissions_matrix) to select the appropriate role for an account based on the types of actions you want that account to perform.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.